# Find minimum value different than zero given some conditions

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator, set

I've started learning `C++` `Sets` and `Iterators` and I can't figure if I'm doing this correctly since I'm relatively new to programming.

I've created a `Set` of a `struct` with a custom comparator that puts the items in a decreasing order. Before receiving the input I don't know how many items my `Set` will contain. It can contain any number of items from `0` to `1000`.

Here are the `Set`definitions:

```
typedef struct Pop {
    int value_one; int node_value;
} Pop;

struct comparator {
    bool operator() (const Pop& lhs, const Pop& rhs) const {
        if (rhs.value_one == lhs.value_one) {
            return lhs.node_value < rhs.node_value;
        } else { return rhs.value_one < lhs.value_one;}
    }
};

set<Pop, comparator> pop;
set<Pop>::iterator it;
```

And this is the algorithm. It should find a `minimum` value and print that value. If it does not find (the function `do_some_work(...)` returns `0`), it should print `"Zero work found!\n"`:

```
int minimum = (INT_MAX) / 2; int result;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //....
    //After reading input and adding values to the SET gets to this part
    Pop next;
    Pop current;
    for (it = pop.begin(); it != pop.end() && minimum != 1; it++) {
        current = *it;
        temp_it = it;
        temp_it++;
        if (temp_it != pop.end()) {
            next = *temp_it;
            // This function returns a integer value that can be any number from 0 to 5000.
            // Besides this, it checks if the value found is less that the minimum (declared as global)  and different of 0 and if so
            // updates the minimum value. Even if the set as 1000 items and at the first iteration the value
            //  found is 1, minimum is updated with 1 and we should break out of the for loop.
            result = do_some_work(current.node_value); 
            if (result > 0 && next.value_one < current.value_one) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            result = do_some_work(current.node_value); 
        }
    }
    if (minimum != (INT_MAX) / 2) {
        printf("%d\n", minimum);
    } else {
        printf("Zero work found!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here are some possible outcomes.

If the `Set` is empty it should print `Zero work found!`

If the `Set` as one item and `do_some_work(current.node_value)` returns a value bigger than `0` it should `printf("%d\n", minimum);` or `Zero work found!` otherwise.

Imagine I have this `Set` (first position `value_one` and second position `node_value`:

```
4 2
3 6
3 7
3 8
3 10
2 34
```

- If in the first iteration `do_some_work(current.node_value)` returns a value bigger than `0`, since all other items `value_one` are smaller, it should break the loop, print the `minimum` and exit the program.
- If in the first iteration `do_some_work(current.node_value)` returns `0`, I advance in the `Set` and since there are `4` items with `value_one` as `3` I must analyze this `4` items because any of these can return a possible valid `minimum` value. If any of these updates the `minimum` value to `1`, it should break the loop, print the `minimum` and exit the program.
- In this case, the last item of the `Set` is only analysed if all other items return `0` or `minimum` value is set to `1`.

For me this is both an algorithmic problem and a programming problem.

**With this code, am I analysing all the possibilities and if `minimum` is `1`, breaking the loop since if `1` is returned there's no need to check any other items?**

Comment: If this isn't a school assignment and you can use std::algorithm stuff, did you consider trying "nth_element"? It can do exactly what you need: find the minimum element (1st element in your case). http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/

Comment: @BeyondSora thanks for pointing that out but `do_some_work(current.node_value); ` is more complex and that can't be used here.

Comment: you can pass a custom comparator into nth_element. You can always do other things in your comparator, if you so incline. ;) It may or may not be good practice...

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But with my code do you think that I'm analysing all the possibilities and if minimum is 1, breaking the loop?